# What is the practical benefit of a mesh of triangles conforming to Euler's formula?

Tags: graph-theory

I am reading an article that describes how to represent land and seafloor surfaces with a bunch of triangles joined at their edges.

The paper says this:

> As employed by ocean modelers, a mesh is the product of a
>   triangulation of a set of points in the plane, so it should therefore
>   satisfy Euler's formula for a simple polygon, whose characteristic
>   equals one. By convention, such polygons are defined in terms of
>   undirected graphs of vertices, edges, and faces that are, in our case,
>   triangular. Thus, we require that V - E + T = 1, where V = vertices, E
>   (undirected) edges, and T triangles appear in a mesh.

What is the practical implication of a mesh of triangles satisfying Euler's formula? Does it mean that no triangle will overlap another triangle (see Figure 1 below)? Or, does it mean that no triangle will touch another triangle in the middle of an edge (see Figure 2 below)? Or, does it mean something else?

[image: overlapping triangles, one triangle touching another on an edge]

Comment: The description of a "good" triangulation (and therefore of your Question) conflates a few ideas.  First we should point out that Euler's formula applies to polygonal surfaces of polyhedra.  So, one requirement to apply Euler's formula is that the polygons (such as triangles) meet edge to edge or vertex to vertex.  A triangulation of a planar region can (with some assumptions) be converted to the surface of a polyhedral solid.  Your Question asks about the "practical benefit" of this situation, which has meaning in the context of what use the triangulation will have, e.g. seafloor elevation.